# How to create rectangle form point x and y

Tags: swift

I want to calculate area rectangle form point x and y

[image: Example Picture]

```
class Point{
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    init(x: Int,y: Int){
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}
class Rectangle{

       func area() -> Int{
           //I have no idea
       }

}
```

Comment: Your rectangle class is missing a few obvious properies, don't you think? like width anf height?

Comment: You have two points.  The differences of the x's is width, the difference y's is height.  Area is width * height.

Comment: You need an initializer for Rectangle that takes two points and stores those as properties of the rectangle.

Comment: Start with task #1 from the assignment, not with task #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Point {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    init(x: Int, y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

class Rectangle {
    let nw: Point
    let se: Point
    init(nw: Point, se: Point) {
        self.nw = nw
        self.se = se
    }

    func area() -> Int {
        return (se.y - nw.y) * (se.x - nw.x)
    }

    func containsPoint(_ p: Point) -> Bool {
        let isContainHorizontal = (nw.x <= p.x) && (p.x <= se.x )
        let isContainVertical = (nw.y <= p.y) && (p.y <= se.y)
        return isContainHorizontal && isContainVertical
    }

    func combine(_ rect: Rectangle) -> Rectangle {
        return Rectangle(nw: Point(x: max(nw.x, rect.nw.x), y: max(nw.y, rect.nw.y)), se: Point(x: min(se.x, rect.se.x), y: min(se.y, rect.se.y)))
    }
}
```

output

```
2. 6

3. false, true

4. 1
```

Comment: Regarding the answer number 4:  Area should be 12. You are mixing where to use min and where to use max in your combine method. the correct would be `return Rectangle(nw: Point(x: min(nw.x, rect.nw.x), y: min(nw.y, rect.nw.y)), se: Point(x: max(se.x, rect.se.x), y: max(se.y, rect.se.y)))`